# Top level port with records in VHDL with multiple direction

Tags: vhdl

I want to use records as I have multiple ports which at the same time are composed by multiple signals. The issue is that some signals are in and some are out (AXI stream, specifically).

I want to avoid doing this:

```
    port (
        s0_axis_tvalid : in STD_LOGIC;
        s0_axis_tdata  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (Data_Width-1 downto 0);
        s0_axis_tlast  : in STD_LOGIC;
        s0_axis_tready : out STD_LOGIC;

        s1_axis_tvalid : in STD_LOGIC;
        s1_axis_tdata  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (Data_Width-1 downto 0);
        s1_axis_tlast  : in STD_LOGIC;
        s1_axis_tready : out STD_LOGIC;

        m0_axis_tvalid : out STD_LOGIC;
        m0_axis_tdata  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (Data_Width-1 downto 0);
        m0_axis_tlast  : out STD_LOGIC;
        m0_axis_tready : in STD_LOGIC);
```

So, I want to have some records looking like this:

```
type AXIS_Slave is record
    s_axis_tvalid :  STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_tdata  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (Data_Width-1 downto 0);
    s_axis_tlast  :  STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_tready :  STD_LOGIC;
end record AXIS_Slave;

type AXIS_Master is record
    s_axis_tvalid :  STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_tdata  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (Data_Width-1 downto 0);
    s_axis_tlast  :  STD_LOGIC;
    s_axis_tready :  STD_LOGIC;
end record AXIS_Master;
```

Now, the port in my TOP's entity design should be:

```
Port (
    s0: AXIS_Slave;
    s1: AXIS_Slave;
    m0: AXIS_Master);
```

The problem is that I need to declare in the Port whether it is in or out but the direction of each signal should be defined in the record, which I believe is not allowed as I get a warning "Syntax error near in" or "Syntax error near out".

So, how can I declare a type which has in and out signals?

Comment: In vhdl2008 and previous, entire record needs to have thes same direction.  For Axis, I have record with transaction signals (tdata, tkeep, tstrb, tid tlast, tdest) with tvalid and tready as separate signals. In vhdl2008 this can be be an unconstrained record with lengths defined per port.  It also makes verification easier as you only need to check transactions order.

Comment: @Tricky you also can have just one record and all signals are `inout`. In such a case, you need to initialize objects of that record correctly, so the resolution function works correctly. All elements in the record need to be of resolved types. All simulators support this, but synthesis tools like Vivado have problems while Xilinx ISE could handle it correctly.

Comment: In general this problem is solved since VHDL-2019.

Comment: `So, how can I declare a type which has in and out signals?` "A type is characterized by a set of values and a set of operations." (IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.1).  "An _object_ is a named entity that contains (has) a value of a type." (6.4.1). "An interface object has one of the following modes: ...**in** ... **out** ... **input** or **buffer** ... **linkage** ..." (6.5.2). Perhaps the question should be 'How do I declare a composite interface signal object with distinct subelement modes?'

Comment: @user1155120 How do I declare a composite interface signal object with distinct subelement modes? would be much better. Also I would like not to rely on newer VHDL versions to avoid the issue that Paebbels mentions with synthesis tools

Comment: As Tricky commented there's no way to do so in -2008 or earlier revisions. In -2019 See 6.5.2 Interface object declarations there's a mode view declaration that can be used in an interface signal declaration's mode indication as a mode view indication (it's named). Vendor -2019 support could lag significantly. In the mean time 'what can't be cured, must be endured'. You could author a script for generating onerous port clauses and port maps, or do it once and keep templates handy.

Comment: @user1155120 that is the main idea, but the goal was to have a compact file rather than one with a huge port declaration